# Apache Beam :: can't get groupbykey work with session window with java

Tags: java, apache-beam

I've a simple problem.
Lets say I'm reading a parquet file which produces an avro `GenericRecord` object per row, as below.

```
{"name":"john", "surename":"doe", "age":40, "user_pk":"john:doe:40", "unique_attribute":"j1"}
{"name":"john", "surename":"doe", "age":40, "user_pk":"john:doe:40", "unique_attribute":"j2"}
{"name":"john", "surename":"doe", "age":40, "user_pk":"john:doe:40", "unique_attribute":"j3"}
{"name":"john", "surename":"doe", "age":40, "user_pk":"john:doe:40", "unique_attribute":"j4"}

{"name":"paul", "surename":"carl", "age":28, "user_pk":"paul:carl:28", "unique_attribute":"p1"}
{"name":"paul", "surename":"carl", "age":28, "user_pk":"paul:carl:28", "unique_attribute":"p2"}
{"name":"paul", "surename":"carl", "age":28, "user_pk":"paul:carl:28", "unique_attribute":"p3"}
```

this file was flatten on purpose and I would like to un-flatten them.

- we know that the input is ordered and I would like to process them until the next session key, and pass to the next apply in the pipeline, to keep the memory requirement minimal, 
  so the intermediary stage should return `KV<String, Iterable<GenericRecord>>` or even better combined `KV<String, GenericRecord>`.

```
<"john:doe:40", {"name":"john", "surename":"doe", "age":40, ["unique_attribute":"j1", ...]}>
<"paul:carl:28", {"name":"paul", "surename":"carl", "age":28, "user_pk":, ["unique_attribute":"p1", ...]}
```

this is what I've got so far;

```
        pipeline.apply("FilePattern", FileIO.match().filepattern(PARQUET_FILE_PATTERN))
                .apply("FileReadMatches", FileIO.readMatches())
                .apply("ParquetReadFiles", ParquetIO.readFiles(schema))
                .apply("SetKeyValuePK", WithKeys.of(input -> AvroSupport.of(input).extractString("user_pk").get())).setCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), AvroCoder.of(schema)))
                .apply(Window.into(Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardSeconds(5L)))).setCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), AvroCoder.of(schema)))
                .apply("SetGroupByPK", GroupByKey.create()).setCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), IterableCoder.of(AvroCoder.of(schema))))
...
...
```

I don't know if there is a better way of doing it but for now I've used `Sessions.withGapDuration` windowing strategy.
I expected I would get a grouped element `KV<String, Iterable<GenericRecord>> element` in every ~5seconds, but I'm not getting anything after `GroupByKey`, I'm not even sure if `GroupByKey` is actually doing anything, but I know that memory is increasing rapidly so it must be waiting for all the items.

So the question is, how would you setup a windowing function that will allow me to groupbykey.
I've also tried `Combine.byKey`, as it is suppose to be `GroupByKey + Windowing Function` but couldn't implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get the groupby working, but not sure if I understand fully.
I had to add two thinks.
First one (any?) IO operations in Beam doesn't add timestamp.

```
.apply("WithTimestamp", WithTimestamps.of(input -> Instant.now()))
```

second I've added a `Triger` so the `GroupByKey` would actually get triggered. No idea why it wasn't triggering in the first place. I'm sure someone has an explanation for this.

```
.apply("SessionWindow", Window.<KV<String, GenericRecord>>into(Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardSeconds(5L))).triggering(
                        AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                                .withLateFirings(AfterProcessingTime
                                        .pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.ZERO)))
                        .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
                        .discardingFiredPanes())
```

It is not perfect, still had to wait couple of minutes before I see that the `GroupByKey` gets triggered even though the window is only `5s`, but it gets triggered in the end, which is progress.

EDIT:
ok it looks like timestamp wasn't needed, I'm assuming because the window is session based and not time based.
I've also change the setting to streaming

```
        options.as(StreamingOptions.class)
                .setStreaming(true);
```

I hope this helps to someone who is having a similar issues.